# find WkWebView's data consumption

Tags: bandwidth, wkwebview, network-utilization

As far as I have searched there is no way to find how much wkwebview has consumed.(sent/received in bytes)

Is there any possibility that I am not aware of ?

Comment: good question. I'm searching for this answer too. Did you find something?